# How set data-percent value for GaugeMeter dynamically from JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know How to set the data-percent value for GaugeMeter in html5.
Here is the link
http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Customizable-Animated-jQuery-HTML5-Gauge-Meter-Plugin.html

html div:

```
<div class="GaugeMeter"id="test1" data-percent="60" data-label="Percent">
  </div>
```

Initializing the plugin:

```
  $(".GaugeMeter").gaugeMeter();
```

But I want to set this data-percent='60' value to html dynamically from javascript using same plugin.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the plugin but there is not much documentation, so i found no way to adjust a percent and then refresh the element.
Anyway, we can do it with jQuery or at least something similar.

Made a html like this:

```html
<div class="GaugeMeter"id="test1" data-percent="60" data-label="Percent">
  </div>
  <button onclick="initialize()">Initialize gauge</button>
  <button onclick="changePercent()">Change percent to 35%</button>
</body>
```

and a JS like this:

```js
   function initialize()
  {
      $("#test1").gaugeMeter();
  }

  function changePercent()
  {
        $("#test1").data("percent",35);
        $("#test1").empty();
        $("#test1").gaugeMeter();
  }
```

So first you initialize the gauge (you can add the Initialize to the document ready event). Then each time you want to change the percent, you empty the element and simulate a refresh.
To change the html 5 "data" attributes, use jQuery.data() function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a better way. As that plugin does not have a CDN (so we can work it on JSFiddle), i'm not able to do much more research. Glad it helped!